# Multi edit MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I've written a little MVC3 site that let's certain users review Active Directory Accounts.
For audits we are required to keep track off our 'user reviews'. So, once a month I put everything in an SQL database. With the state 'to be checked'.

This looks like this:
[image]

I'd like to have a way that people can quickly approve them by just checking a textbox and saving it.

[image]

How would I go about this?

The 'ReviewState' is a separate object (StateID, StateText, Description, Active).
Possibilities are: Unchecked, Approved, Denied, Silently Approved, ...

Comment: If your ReviewState is a Bool you can just use an checkbox. and post the complete list back and save/update them one by one

Comment: The 'ReviewState' is a separate object (StateID, StateText, Description, Active).

Comment: Ok but there will be an property that will say it is approved or not right? If so just bind your checkboxes to that property

Answer (score 1):

Create a ReviewState model and a strongly typed partial view for it containing StateId, StateText, Description etc).

Your parent model should contain a list of ReviewStateModel's. In the main view, loop through that and render a partial for each model in the list.

You may need to add an Id so that you can identify each review model on the server side.

Comment: This looks like the best approach to this. Is there a way I can loop through all partial views on postback?

Comment: Your parent view should have a parent model, which contains the List<ReviewStateModel> ReviewStates. When you post, your controller action receives the parent view model. You can then loop through each  review state. I would actually break the parent model into containing different sub-models, one for each type of section on the page (Accounts to Validate, Subordinate Accounts to validate)

Answer (score 0):

Create a ViewModel to be used in your view:

```
public class AccountViewModel
{
    public AccountInfo Account { get; set; }
    public ReviewState Review { get; set; }
}
```

This way you can add a checkbox for `Approve` like this:

```
@Html.CheckboxFor(x => x.Active);
```

You will get this model back to your post action. The only thing left is extract data and update database.

I might not be accurate with property names here and code is written from my head but I think you get the point